# Sample icons lining on same line

Tags: css

Can you explain how can I make both facebook icons on same line? 
This is simple code but I'm not good at css

```
<i><h1 align="center">Lorem Ipsum</h1></i>
<p>
     <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRcJVzb8HeSBBgdqKTmAhtBwG0EeMuO660TwErH9HaXPf76JFp5fw' width="95px" heigh="85px"> 
</p>   
<i><h3 align="center">Lorem</h3></i>
<p style="text-align: right;margin-right: 25px; font-size: 21px;margin-top:-15px;">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRcJVzb8HeSBBgdqKTmAhtBwG0EeMuO660TwErH9HaXPf76JFp5fw" width="95px" heigh="85px">
</p>
```

[And this is the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vjt4vxmL/1/)

Correct demo - https://jsfiddle.net/vjt4vxmL/2/

Comment: "on same line" is not very clear, that could be horizontal or vertical. please explain better

Comment: Same line horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structure is rather odd, but you can just decrease the height of the iframe to horizontally line up the buttons with the image:

```
<iframe height="36"...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vjt4vxmL/3/

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your first image. This code should put the buttons right next to each other just replace the word class in the code with whatever class you assign.

```
     .class {
      position: relative;
      top: 60px;
      left: -100px;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry i've added correct demo to the question. The problem is the `<iframe>` I can't align them on same line.

Answer (score 0):

To align both next to each other you can use:
`img{float:left;}`

Comment: Thanks and sorry i've added correct demo to the question. The problem is the `<iframe>` I can't align them on same line.